# стрелки Slick Slider закрывают попап

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, возникла проблемы при встраивании слайдера в модальное окно, после нажатия на стрелку переключения слайдера, она закрывает попап как бы обновляя страницу.
Я склонялся к тому, что для этих стрелок надо прописать `event.defaultprevented`. Но проблема в том, что слайдер инициализирует эти стрелки после открытия страницы.

Так вот, как можно в JS прописать, чтобы для класса `slick-arrow` добавилась функция JS с `event.defaultprevented` после того как страницы прогрузилась.

Comment: preventDefault, может написал неправильно, так как все загружается поочередно, если не работает поставь свой скрипт после скрипта слайдера

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужна помощь с кодом JS для добавления функции к div с классом slick-arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте с GIT исходник slick: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js и модифицируйте функцию changeSlide(), добавив туда event.preventDefault();

Либо, если вы используете свой шаблон для стрелок, засуньте в него тег < a >, для него event.preventDefault() вставляется.